# Nested JSON dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZD2z.jpg)

Would someone explain why this returns a typeerror?  the attempt is to print the 'bodyhtml'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are trying to access a string index of ret["response"]["results"], which is a list. if you wanted to access the first result, you could change the code to this:

```
ret["response"]["results"][0]["blocks"] # ...
```

Comment: Your answer got me closer.   Still need to get down to the actual text inside the bodyhtml tag.   Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Goose.  I was able to figure it out with your help.

Comment: No problem, lots of people when working with wacky data display get stuff like that mixed up